# does the given sequence always converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Let {$u_n$} and {$v_n$} be two null sequences . Is the sequence {$u_n^{v_n}$} (if the sequence define) always convergent and bounded?
As $u_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. then for a given $0<r<1$ there exists a natural number $k$ such that $|u_n|<r$ for all $n>k$ now if $v_n\ge0$ then $u_n^{v_n}\le r^{v_n}$ for all $n>k$ in that case $\lim u_n^{v_n}\le1$. please help me ? there may be mistake in my approach.

Comment: Try $u_n=1/n$, $v_n=-1/\log\log n$.

Comment: then $u_n$^$v_n$>$n$^$(1/n)$ and it is alawas >1.. what can you say about conver gence and bddness.  @ Gerry myerson

Comment: @AjoyJana, in Gerry Myerson's example $v_n \ln u_n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n} \to +\infty$, so ${u_n}^{v_n} = e^{v_n \ln u_n} \to +\infty$.

Comment: thanks all of you for helping me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the cat is out of the bag, so I'll flesh out my hint into an answer. Let $$u_n={1\over n},\quad v_n=-{1\over\log\log n}$$ Then $$\log(u_n^{v_n})={\log n\over\log\log n}\to\infty$$ as $n\to\infty$, so $u_n^{v_n}$ is unbounded.